# show msg when I click on circle google map ?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, draw

I draw google map in my website. In my database I have coordinates ... I want to get this coordinates and draw circle foreah record in DB. when I draw circle I want to click on it to show text ... this is my code that I draw circles

```
    <script>
// This example creates circles on the map, representing
// populations in the United States.

// First, create an object containing LatLng and population for each city.
var citymap = {};
citymap['chicago'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.878113, -87.629798),
  population: 2842518
};
citymap['newyork'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.714352, -74.005973),
  population: 8143197
};
citymap['losangeles'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.052234, -118.243684),
  population: 3844829
};
var cityCircle;

function initialize() {
  // Create the map.
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -95.712891),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  // Construct the circle for each value in citymap.
  // Note: We scale the population by a factor of 20.
  for (var city in citymap) {
    var populationOptions = {
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map,
      center: citymap[city].center,
      radius: citymap[city].population / 20
    };
    // Add the circle for this city to the map.
    cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
```

my problem is how can I show msg when I click on any circle in my map ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(cityCircle, 'click', function() {
    alert('you message goes here');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps API documentation [shows how to open an infowindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows#open). A simplified example that you could put after your `cityCircle` definition:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(cityCircle, 'click', function() {
  new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: 'hello!'}).open(map, cityCircle);
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work .... :( there is no result

Comment: @AsoooNol: oops, I missed the call to `open` the info window. Try it now?